# Creating a regex that accept first 4 digit prefix and 3 number after

Tags: regex

I need a regex that would validate first 4 digit set and then 3 digits. The first foure digits need to be identical.

Acceptable entries should be for example:

```
7777989  
8888767
```

Invalid entries:

```
7778888
7777abc
8989123
```

Now my problem is that in my code iam creating the regexes based on class names. for example something like this

```
if (currentChar == 'n') regex += '[0-9]'; 
else if (currentChar == 'd') regex += '^[0-9]+$';
```

in above code n and d is class name where n represents "any digit" and d represents "identical digits". So for the above example, the rule would be `ddddnnn`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(\d)\1{3}\d{3}$
```

should do it.

```
^     # Start of string
(\d)  # Match a single digit, capture in group 1
\1{3} # Match the same digit as in group 1, three times
\d{3} # Match three digits (any)
$     # End of string
```

A quick and dirty regex generator (in Python), assuming that all `d` digits have to be identical:

```
def makere(rule):
    first_d = True
    parts = ["^"]
    for letter in rule:
        if letter == "d":
            if first_d:
                parts.append(r"(\d)")
                first_d = False
            else:
                parts.append(r"\1")
        if letter == "n":
            parts.append(r"\d")
    parts.append("$")
    return ''.join(parts)
```

Result:

```
>>> makere("ddddnnn")
'^(\\d)\\1\\1\\1\\d\\d\\d$'
>>> makere("ddnnndd")
'^(\\d)\\1\\d\\d\\d\\1\\1$'
```

Comment: its working when i give 888nnn but not dynamically working when i do dddnnn

Comment: I can't follow you. Which exact strings that you tried were or weren't matched the way you expected?